# Tkinter how to detect if text widget content is too long?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm just needing something that can tell if the content in a 1 line text widget is too long, thus needing a horizontal scrollbar.

I have searched questions others have posted and found a solution for a vertical scrollbar, but it sadly doesn't work as accurately with the horizontal.

My solution for vertical:

```
if self.verse_box.cget('height') < int(self.verse_box.index('end-1c').split('.')[0]):
    print "Too many lines"
```

But if I switch it like so it doesn't work as some characters are smaller and thus can have more fit in the line:

```
if self.verse_box.cget('width') < int(self.tags_box.index('end-1c').split('.')[1]):
    print "This one line is too long"
```

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks! ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any widget that supports scrolling, you can call the `.xview()` or `.yview()` method without parameters to get the current start/end fractions of the visible area along that axis.  If the entire contents are already visible, this will be the tuple `(0.0, 1.0)`.  If the returned value is anything else, a scrollbar is needed to see the entire contents.

Comment: Thank you so much! I greatly appreciate it! ^-^